# About partial uniqueness of SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In order to prove non-uniqueness of singular vectors when a repeated singular value is present, the book (Trefethen-Bau, considered the most authotitative book on the subject), argues as follows: Let $\sigma$ be the first singular value of A, and $v_{1}$ the corresponding singular vector. Let $w$ be another linearly independent vector such that $||Aw||=\sigma$, and construct a third vector $v_{2}$ belonging to span of $v_{1}$ and $w$, and orthogonal to $v_{1}$. All three vectors are unitary, so $w=av_{1}+bv_{2}$ with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, and $v_{2}$ is constructed (Gram-Schmidt style) as follows:

$$ {v}_{2}= \dfrac{{w}-({v}_{1}^{T} w ){v}_{1}}{|| {w}_{1}-({v}_{1}^{T} {w} ){v}_{1} ||_{2}}$$

> Now, Trefethen says, $||A||=\sigma$, so $||Av_{2}||\le \sigma$ **but
>   this must be an equality** (and so $v_{2}$ is another singular vector
>   relative to $\sigma$), **since otherwise we would have
>   $||Aw||<\sigma$**, in contrast with the hypothesis.

How that? I cannot see any elementary application of triangle inequality or Schwarz inequality  to prove this claim.

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why the rest of the proof is valid? I.e. up to the part of "We conclude that, if the singular vector $v_1$  is not unique, then the corresponding singular value $\sigma_1$ is not simple" - I don't understand why the fact that $||Av_2|| = \sigma_1$ leads to anything... also what does "simple" even means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\|Av_1\|=\sigma$. Assume, $\|Av_2\| < \sigma$. Now, $w= av_1+bv_2$, so \begin{equation}
\|Aw\|^2=|a|^2 \|Av_1\|^2 + |b|^2 \|Av_2\|^2 + 2ab\langle Av_1,Av_2\rangle < \sigma^2 + 2ab\langle Av_1,Av_2\rangle.\quad (*)
\end{equation}

Let $u_1$ be the first left-singular vector of $A$, so that $Av_1 = \sigma u_1$. Now, $b Av_2 = Aw - v_1^Tw \sigma u_1$, whereby $2a\langle\sigma u_1, Aw- a\sigma u_1\rangle = 2a\sigma u_1^TAw - 2a^2\sigma^2=0$, due to $u_1^TA=\sigma v_1$. Thus, the last term in $(*)$ disappears, which completes the claim.

Comment: Very well exposed, thanks. I think it only applies to real case, however.

Comment: I did not look at it, but I don't immediately see what might prevent the argument for going through for the complex case...

Comment: the last math expression is missing a transpose on the $v_1$